# BATCH request in odata v4 service is not returning the CR as specified in RFC2046 when run on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, odata

I have problem with odata service .
I created a simple application in dotnet core (surce in https://github.com/siasty/Ui5_Odatav4) where I use batch request.

For example, it is available on two systems linux Http://51.68.141.73 and windows http://51.83.132.0

When I checking Batch Response I observe on the linux system CR (ASCII 13, \r) is missing in response .
this is only on linux!

does anyone know the possibility that the respond return in a windows style?
is it possible to transform respond using serwer www nginx or apache?

Comment: That always happens.  Windows uses for end of line a '\n' while unix/linux uses '\r'

Comment: Now I know :) but is there any solution? is it possible to somehow filter the answers by using NGINX or APACHE?

Comment: Windows you get 0x0D, 0x0A while linux you get only the 0x0A.  So instead of using ReadLine() you can read until the '\r'.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I use the official UI5 framework to parsing batch reqest, he works according to the standard RFC2046 (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt) 

"The Content-Type field for multipart entities requires one parameter,
   "boundary". The boundary delimiter line is then defined as a line
   consisting entirely of two hyphen characters ("-", decimal value 45)
   followed by the boundary parameter value from the Content-Type header
   field, optional linear whitespace, and a terminating CRLF."

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree or disagree with your logic.  RFC2046 in some sections says you need both CRLF and others CRLF (which doesn't imply both).  So I assume in RFC2046 where it doesn't specifically say BOTH one is acceptable.  So it depends on the context type if both are required.  Are you getting any errors?  I've been reading RFCs for 40 years and you need a lawyers degree to read these documents.  The RFC are written by committee which consists who work for competing companies.When Interoperability becomes a factor the specs are rewritten with multiple options.This sound like a option.

Comment: Sure, you may be right, but I reported a bug to the authors of the framework (https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2830#issuecomment-593406590 and https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2984) 
and claim that the answer does not comply with the standard and their parser doesn't accept an answer

Comment: RFC specfications are written by committee.  A preliminary specification is released and hardware/software vendors develop products.  Before specification is released a compatibility test is performed which often fails.  Then committee looks for a simple solution to fix issue.  Often is just involves adding a word like BOTH.  Most cases it doesn't matter if the end of line is one or two characters.   When you are searching for an ascii string you want to make sure it is at the beginning of a line and not in the middle of binary data.

Comment: However,  batch request MUST contain a Content-Type header with value multipart/mixed (https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part1-protocol.html#sec_MultipartBatchResponse ) in RFC2046 the section 5.1.1 about "multipart" (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1) we can read boundary parameter requires end of line  CRLF

Comment: I'm not sure.  The specification does not says CRLF is always 0x0D 0x0A.  It just says line termination.  You can email the owners of the spec (at the end of spec) to see if they really mean both.  I've never seen a specification that required both since Linux/Unix doesn't use both.

Comment: ok thanks for the discussion, that two heads are better than one :) I wrote to the authors of the spec, I hope I will get a reply

Answer (score 0):

new Microsoft ODL 7.7.3 releases solved the problem